# how to compress single file to tar.gz

Tags: python, linux

Am trying to compress a single file

the required output ==> `myfile.tar.gz`==>`myfile.tar`==>`myfile.bin`

the command I run ...

```
subprocess.call(['tar', '-zcvf', '/path/to/desitnation/myfile.tar.gz', "./path/to/file/myfile.bin"]
```

the output I get is

`myfile.tar.gz`==>`myfile.tar`==>`./path/to/file/myfile.bin`

Answer (score 0):

`tar` has a `-C` (`--directory`) option to cause it to change directories before it starts processing files:

```
subprocess.call(['tar',
  '-C', '/path/to/file/',
  '-zcvf',
  '/path/to/destination/myfile.tar.gz', "myfile.bin"])
```

See the [`tar` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) for details.

---

You can accomplish the same thing using the `cwd` parameter to `subprocess.call`:

```
subprocess.call(['tar',
  '-zcvf',
  '/path/to/destination/myfile.tar.gz', "myfile.bin"], 
  cwd='/path/to/file')
```

See the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for details.